# TYPO3 Form: HMAC could not be validated

Tags: forms, typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x

I use the TYPO3 form extension and integrate the form as follows:

I created a new page in the TYPO3 backend and integrated the contact form there.

In TypoScript I create the following variable:

```
CONTACTFORM = CONTENT
        CONTACTFORM {
          table = tt_content
          select {
               pidInList = 23
               includeRecordsWithoutDefaultTranslation = 1
                }
           }
```

In the fluid template I call them as follows:

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
                <div class="row">
                    <f:format.htmlentitiesDecode>{CONTACTFORM}</f:format.htmlentitiesDecode>
                </div>
            </div>
```

When I send the form then I get this error:

```
(1/1) #1581862822 TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Http\BadRequestException

The HMAC of the form could not be validated.
```

Looks like the hidden form field tx_form_formframework[__trustedProperties] is also parsed how can I prevent this?

Comment: It is so wonderful to work with Typo3, after each update you discover yourself anew.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
lib.fluidcontact = CONTENT
lib.fluidcontact {
    table = tt_content
    select {
        pidInList = 23
        includeRecordsWithoutDefaultTranslation = 1
    }
}
```

and in the fluid template:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.fluidcontact" />
```